# Need a solution to warn user for page expiry using Angular 5 service?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a lot of page with a lot of forms on them. I want to create a service to monitor this form. The form is bound to a data model object with huge number of properties. I tried watching the data model object using a library called watchjs but thats too heavy on the browser memory. I want to be able to listen to the changes when user stops typing so that after 60 seconds i can warn him/her that the the changes are going to be saved.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I would suggest you monitor a global window level keypress event instead of checking each of the individual forms manually (as you said it's huge)

So simply `window.addEventListener('keypress', () => {})` and put your counter reset logic in there should be sufficient.

It's not the best solution but it should be the most performance friendly one. You don't want to sacrifice performance for this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question, how does the window.addEventListener() work on the background? is the event listener applied to each component in the window individually or just the state of the window?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya It catches all key press events globally by default if the propagation is not blocked by inner members. So yes when user input in any of the component you have, you should get the event triggered for window object as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ReactiveForms, you can use the observable valueChanges with a debounceTime. Some like

```
this.myForm=this.fb.group({
    field1: '',
     ...
  });
this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(3000)
    ).subscribe(()=>{
       alert("no changes in 3 seconds")
    })
```

Only when a change happens, if pass 3 seconds and no more change, something happens